# ORA-00904: Invalid identifier when using dbms_random.value

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

[This article here](http://kwatog.com/blog/oracle/select-random-records-in-oracle/) suggests using dbms_random.value to select random values from a table.

My query

```
select value1, value2 from 
(select value1, value2 from my.table order by dbms_random.value) 
where rownum <100;
```

Gives me

```
Error at Command Line:2 Column://column after the 'by'). 
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00904: : invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Insufficient user priviledges. Don't have access to the dbms_random package.

Answer (score 3):

You need to GRANT EXECUTE to your schema. Login as your SYS user and run the following, replacing '**your-schema-name**' with the Oracle user who you wish to allow run DBMS_RANDOM.

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON DBMS_RANDOM TO your-schema-name;
```